# Como ordenar array de forma decrescente?

Tags: php, array

Estou com o seguinte problema, após fazer uma `array` `push, quero retornar a quantidade de repetição de um termo pra isso fiz:

```
$key = str_replace(array(',','.','https','/','#','!','@','&','?','\\',':','\'','”','(',')', 'ª','º','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','“','"','','','','-','','','❤','','','','','k','','',''), ' ', strtolower($key));           

$wreply = split(' ',$key);

foreach ($wreply as $wkr) 
{
     if (strlen($wkr) > 3) {array_push($words, $wkr);}
} 

$contagem = array_count_values($words);
```

esse código me gera a palavra e a quantidade que se repetiu

*Exemplo:*

```
a => 5
```

Quero ordenar pelo valor dele, usei o `rsort` assim:

```
$sort   = rsort($contagem);

foreach ($sort as $key => $value) 
{
    echo "$key => $value,";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa o [array_count_values()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) junto com o [arsort()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.arsort.php).

```
$array = array('apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'banana', 'apple',
    'pear', 'kiwi', 'kiwi', 'kiwi');
    
$output = array_count_values($array);
arsort($output);

print_r($output);
```

Saída

```
Array
(
    [kiwi] => 3
    [apple] => 2
    [pear] => 2
    [orange] => 1
    [banana] => 1
)
```

Obs: usei uma resposta como referência do [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1170825/2610980) e adaptei ao seu problema.

Answer (score 2):

Duas coisas:

1. O `rsort` reordena a própria array original, e não retorna uma nova (retorna `true` ou `false` indicando se a operação foi ou não bem-sucedida).
2. O `rsort` joga fora as chaves da array original, e você parece querer manter as chaves. Isso você resolve usando [`arsort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php).

Portanto:

```
arsort($contagem); // reordena in-place como o rsort, mas mantendo as chaves
foreach ($contagem as $key => $value) 
{
    echo "$key => $value,";
}
```